# How to go about load testing of CometD on tomcat

Tags: tomcat, cometd

I have deployed cometd 3.0.1 on tomcat 7. I have planned to do load testing with this setup.

Can anyone help on how to go about this?

Will testing using demos given [here](https://github.com/cometd/cometd) will be good enough? (I will start my cometd setup and try to connect these demo example to my cometd server deployed in tomcat)

Answer (score 0):

CometD ships benchmark modules with load generation tools, see https://github.com/cometd/cometd/blob/master/README.md and the modules at https://github.com/cometd/cometd/tree/master/cometd-java/cometd-java-benchmark.

You can reuse the client benchmark module as is, but for the server you will need to replicate in Tomcat what has been done on the server benchmark module.

If you need to build a custom load test tool with your own messages and logic, then by all means start by looking very carefully at what the CometD benchmark modules do, and how they do it. They are the result of years of tuning and best practices.